# Find lines that have partial matches

Tags: bash, duplicates

So I have a text file that contains a large number of lines. Each line is one long string with no spacing, however, the line contains several pieces of information. The program knows how to differentiate the important information in each line. The program identifies that the first 4 numbers/letters of the line coincide to a specific instrument. Here is a small example portion of the text file.

**example text file**

```
   1002IPU3...
   POIPIPU2...
   1435IPU1...
   1812IPU3...
   BFTOIPD3...
   1435IPD2...
```

As you can see, there are two lines that contain 1435 within this text file, which coincides with a specific instrument. However these lines are not identical. The program I'm using can not do its calculation if there are duplicates of the same station (ie, there are two 1435* stations). I need to find a way to search through my text files and identify if there are any duplicates of the partial strings that represent the stations within the file so that I can delete one or both of the duplicates. If I could have BASH script output the number of the lines containing the duplicates and what the duplicates lines say, that would be appreciated. I think there might be an easy way to do this, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `sort -k1.1,1.4 file.txt | uniq -Dw4` work for you?

Comment: So i attempted your command and I got       `>> $ sort -k1.1,1.4 text.file | uniq -Dw4 \
                          uniq: illegal option -- D \
                          usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]] `    Did I do something wrong? Just curious if youd come across something like this...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to Stack Overflow and sometimes my comments look odd. When I use " \ ", that is just to note that that is a new line.

Comment: That means you are not using GNU `uniq` so my solution won't work unless modified..

Answer (score 0):

Use following Python script(syntax of python 2.7 version used)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

file_name = "device.txt"
f1 = open(file_name,'r')
device = {}
line_count = 0
for line in f1:
        line_count += 1
        if device.has_key(line[:4]):
                device[line[:4]] = device[line[:4]] + "," + str(line_count)
        else:
                device[line[:4]] = str(line_count)
f1.close()
print device
```

here the script reads each line and initial 4 character of each line are considered as device name and creates a key value pair `device` with key representing device name and value as line numbers where we find the string(device name)

following would be output

```
{'POIP': '2', '1435': '3,6', '1002': '1', '1812': '4', 'BFTO': '5'}
```

this might help you out!!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have specified that I want to check all the different possible duplicate stations, not just station 1435, so I want to make sure that in my actual file that there are not duplicates of station POIP or station 1812, etc.  The file I actually am working with is over 800 lines long. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is detect if there are duplicates (not necessarily count or eliminate them), this would be a good starting point:

```
awk '{ if (++seen[substr($0, 1, 4)] > 1) printf "Duplicates found : %s\n",$0 }' inputfile.txt
```

For that matter, it's a good starting point for counting or eliminating, too, it'll just take a bit more work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of duplicates:

```
awk '{a[substr($0,1,4)]++} END {for (i in a) {if(a[i]>1) print i": "a[i]}}' test.in
1435: 2
```

or:

```
{
  a[substr($0,1,4)]++          # put prefixes to array and count them
} 
END {                          # in the end
  for (i in a) {               # go thru all indexes
    if(a[i]>1) print i": "a[i] # and print out the duplicate prefixes and their counts
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly roundabout but this should work-

```
cut -c 1-4 file.txt | sort -u > list
for i in `cat list`;
do
echo -n "$i "
grep -c ^"$i" file.txt     #This tells you how many occurrences of each 'station'
done
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the ones that occur more than once.